# What is a 'filter box'?

Tags: meaning

What is a 'filter box', and why they are installed near pools?

I came across this word in a story by David Malouf, *Towards Midnight*. But unfortunately, I couldn't find a definition in any dictionary.

Here are two snippets that might give you an idea of how it's used:

> **1**: *It was the clatter of the filter boxes in the pool two levels below. A breeze must have sprung up*.

> **2**: *The disturbance he made as he rocked the water [...] set the filter boxes dancing and beating the air just as she had first heard it*.

The pics I found online don't fit the description, as 'the filter boxes' should be clattering and beating the air. I can't imagine what they look like. :(

Comment: Don't you think this belongs more clearly somewhere like Literature?

The first example seems clearly correct. The second seems rather unlikely.

Do you doubt that a 'filter box' is a box containing a filter, and such things are installed near pools because pool  water needs filtering?

Comment: You left out a crucial part: "The disturbance he made as he rocked the water, **which was all tilted planes of moonlight and dark**, set the filter boxes dancing..." It seems to be talking about the *reflections* of the filter boxes. Remember that this is literature, not a report. The filter boxes contain pumps, and if they appear to be dancing, then in the protagonist's imagination they might be beating the air too.